# Declaring text to a variable shows Text string must be rendered within a <Text> component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a React Native app where i'm mapping an array and assigning a text to a variable. But this throws the red screen showing 'Text string must be rendered within a Text component'. Here's where the error is throwing:

```js
export default class index extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { payments } = this.props;
    const filteredPaymentList = this.props.payments
      const filteredPaymentList = payments.filter(item => {
      if (item.id === 'stripe') {
        item.id = 'stripe_connect';
      }
      return typeof Config.Payments[item.id] !== 'undefined';
    });

    return (
      <View>
        ...
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

The if condition is where the error generates. Why is it happening? It's not even in the return section. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in the code

1. filteredPaymentList which is a const is declared twice the second line is not required at all.
2. You have put ... inside the view, which is considered as a string and requires a Text to wrap and causes the above error. Better change it to actual code and it will work normally.

Comment: Can you please suggest how can i change this. Because it seems to me that i have put the code in render not return. So, how can i change this to resolve the issue? @GuruparanGiritharan

Comment: remove the ... and then it will display an empty view, then you can map and show your items in the filteredPaymentList array

Comment: I have the filterered items showing in the view which i have not provided. So, i showed like .... I just want to remove the text component thing from the if condition. Can you please show how can i do that?

Comment: I dont see a text component also, can you show the full code to see the actual issue ?